# jquery click row will select the other row

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I really don't know whats the problem with my code but everytime I clicked a row, it will highlight the other row above. This happens with my two .html files with jqgrid in it. Is anybody here face the same problem with mine, how can I solve it? thanks

**Here's the code... I deleted some code here to make it shorter. My main problem here in my jqgrid only. [my .js code](http://jayannpatangan.blogspot.com/2011/07/my-js-file-newsp1js.html) and my [.html code](http://jayannpatangan.blogspot.com/2011/07/my-code-html-with-jqgrid-problem.html)**

I can display the data in my jqgrid. but when i try to select a row by clinking it, it dont highlight and the other row will. Some rows is good while the others were not.

Comment: SO is for specific questions, not general questions. Post some code code, link to a nonfunctioning page and ask a specific question. Like `when you look at this example page and click on row 1, row 2 is selected. Can someone help explain why?` Questions like `something is weird, anyone else see weird stuff too?` is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't posted the test data which you use. The most common reason of the wrong behavior with the row selection is the **wrong ids** for the rows. It's not permitted to have id duplicates on one HTML page. In case of id duplicates in the rowids, the first row with the same id will be typically selected.

Comment: ohhh, I see. Yes, my some of my grid datas has same row IDs. Thank you for the help. I really appreciate your help Oleg. By the way Oleg, I still haven't tried your answer with my other question before this one because i was stuck in this. thanks again.

Comment: @jayAnn: You are welcome! With another answer - not a problem.